Determine Daylight savings time for US Cities prior to 1967
I'm working on a problem where I need to get date times and get their UTC offset.
The data that I get is a date a time and longitude and latitude.
I am currently using pytz and timezonefinder to find the timezone and get utc offset
def get_utc_offset_from_obj(datetime_obj: datetime, timezone) -> str:
    timezone = pytz.timezone(timezone)
    localized_date = timezone.localize(datetime_obj)
    offset = localized_date.utcoffset()
    total_minutes = int(offset.total_seconds() / 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(abs(total_minutes), 60)
    sign = '-' if total_minutes < 0 else '+'
    formatted_offset = f"{sign}{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}"
    return formatted_offset

The problem is that apparently before 1967 US States didn't have uniform DST so within the same timezone some states or counties may adopt daylight savings time and some may not. Which makes the code above not accurate.
For example Texas is part of the America/Chicago timezone but During the years from 1945 to 1966 it didn't adopt Daylight savings time. If I would get the timezone from the coordinates then get the UTC offset it would give me that the timezone adopted DST.
I'm wondering if timezonefinder or pytz can give me the data I am looking for.
As I mentioned I tried converting geo coordinates into timezone then getting the offset from utc of that timezone on the specific date. It didn't work because for the us specifically there were changes in the timezones where within the same timezone different states (sometimes even different counties within the same state) might choose to switch to dst and others won't.

The further back you go in history, the more details fade into obscurity. Mostly out of interest: what’s your use case where it matters whether a timestamp half a century ago is an hour off?

I don't get it... if a state adopted DST on/off on a certain date, DST will just be zero before. So what are you looking for? Besides, it might not be just DST; some regions might even change their base UTC offset over time...

You should two modules: Python's standard module zoneinfo(which is available since Python3.9) + timezonefinder.
pip install timezonefinder
From the documentation:
The zoneinfo module provides a concrete time zone implementation to support the IANA time zone database.
Why it should Work?
The Time Zone Database (often called tz or zoneinfo) contains code and data that represent the history of local time for many representative locations around the globe. It is updated periodically to reflect changes made by political bodies to time zone boundaries, UTC offsets, and daylight-saving rules.
Check this Link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html
Check this other Link: https://www.iana.org/time-zones
A code example to calculate Offset for a given coordinate and time:
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

datetime_object = datetime(1965, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0)  # July 1, 1965
latitude = 4.9686 
longitude = -1.9018 

tf = TimezoneFinder()
timezone_name = tf.timezone_at(lat=latitude, lng=longitude)

timezone = ZoneInfo(timezone_name)

localized_date = datetime_object.astimezone(timezone)
offset = localized_date.utcoffset()

print("UTC Offset:", offset)


And this is more accurate than OP’s pytz usage because…?

Thi is already the same approach I am using but it does not work since the states that now have the same timezone didn't follow rhe same daylight saving in the 1960s and 1950s
